# User view in fragment for methods

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a fragment and in its onCreateView method I call other methods where I try to send the view as parameter:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_fragment, container, false);

        getDashboardDBData(view, periodKey, periodValue);

        return view;
    }

//Get data for dashboard from Database
    private void getDashboardDBData(final View view, final String periodKey, final String periodValue){

        final ScrollView dashboardData = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.dashboardScrollView);
    }
```

XML(part of it - the beginning of it to be more precise):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Medium"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dashboardUpperLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
        android:elevation="17dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.007"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="163dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/dashboardMainLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Period"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/periodSpinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/periodSpinner"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/periodSpinner"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="31dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintBottom_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="216dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardScrollView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1">
```

The issue is that in getDashboardDBData when I try to access dashboardScrollView it gets returned as null reference...any idea why?
Thank you for your help!
ISSUE DISCOVERED:
I have a spinner with an onClickListener inside onCreateView (did not think it is relevant) and it calls the getDashboardDBData, but the view it send is different, look:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String periodKey= dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String periodValue = lPeriods.get(periodKey);

                setPeriodKey(periodKey);
                setPeriodValue(periodValue);

                dropdown.getSelectedView();
                dropdown.setEnabled(false);

                getDashboardDBData(view, periodKey, periodValue);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                // sometimes you need nothing here
            }
        });
```

This listener is inside onViewCreated...any idea how to make it send the proper view?

Comment: Yes I checked a great deal of times

Comment: Sorry, deleted my original comment by mistake. Can you access any other control from `dashboard_fragment ` to see what happens?

Comment: Nothing from dashboar_fragment gets returned..no element

Comment: Do you have more than one `dashboard_fragment ` (for different resolutions)?. I see nothing weird on your code, it should work. I'd also tray a clean build just in case it is stuck on an old version of your layout.

Answer (score 0):

This means that a View with id `R.id.dashboardScrollView` doesn't exist in the inflated view. Ensure that it is a part of the view hierarchy.

Comment: It is part of it

Comment: Can you post the xml?

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 0):

It is because the view has not be created and you have passed the view to the method `getDashboardDBData` and called `findViewById` on that view.I would recommend use `onViewCreated` that  means the view for that fragment has been created and you can find the child view now

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening because `onCreateView` creates the Fragment's view, but that doesn't mean is available. There is another method `onViewCreated` which is called inmediately after `onCreateView`.

In `onViewCreated` the view is already inflated, so it is available, happens after `onCreateView` and among the arguments of the method you can find a `View` which it is the view inflated, using that view you can find anything inside of it.

```
@Override
onViewCreated(... View view) {

    ScrollView dashboardData = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.dashboardScrollView);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with something I did not post, a onItemSelectedListener of a spinner:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String periodKey= dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String periodValue = lPeriods.get(periodKey);

                setPeriodKey(periodKey);
                setPeriodValue(periodValue);

                dropdown.getSelectedView();
                dropdown.setEnabled(false);

                getDashboardDBData(view, periodKey, periodValue);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                // sometimes you need nothing here
            }
        });
```

The listener had its own view, so I simply changed the parameter's name like this:

```
dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                String periodKey= dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
                String periodValue = lPeriods.get(periodKey);

                setPeriodKey(periodKey);
                setPeriodValue(periodValue);

                dropdown.getSelectedView();
                dropdown.setEnabled(false);

                getDashboardDBData(view, periodKey, periodValue);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                // sometimes you need nothing here
            }
        });
```

Thank you all and I am sorry for not posting everything!